# Heroku deploy with react

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, frontend, create-react-app

I just did my first deploy using create-react-app-buildpack, and in my test running it local in the browser it looks like this: [image]
But the moment I open it in heroku it goes like this:[image]
The content of my page is actually srolling through my page header and it lost some of its styling.
I don't know if this is normal or if I'm missing some dependencies or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you press `F12` in Google Chrome, and navigate to Network tab, press `F5`, it should give you an idea of what resources/urls aren't reachable. Usually, it's a relative path problem or something to do with the way your React project was built (Something to do with the `homepage` entry in your `package.json` - see [Here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths))

Comment: I modified the homepage and the error still happens. Also checked my css in the network tab and found nothing diferent between the two

Comment: Some styles can be cached by the browser. Try a hard refresh, and check whether you have the same situation using a couple of different browsers. If that doesn't solve it, you will have to use the developer tools to pinpoint exactly the styles that seem to be missing, and trace them to the CSS file that contains them. You can then compare the same file on both environments...